# Trouble with qsort with key/value structs in a btree

Tags: c

I'm trying to sort key/val structs in an array that it's a tree node of a b-tree. When I insert a key/val struct into a node I place it at the end of the struct then perform a qsort.

```c
struct kv 
{
   char *key;   //This is the key
   int  lba;    //The value of the key
   unsigned char size;   //Size of key for memcmp.
};

struct tnode 
{
    unsigned char nkeys;
    unsigned char keysize;                   
    kv *items[205];
...
};

int compare_key(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    const kv *A = (const kv *) a;
    const kv *B = (const kv *) b;

    print_kv(A);
    print_kv(B);

    //Why return thesee? It's the right most element ergo it's pointing to it's parent's block.
    if (A->key == NULL)
        return INT_MAX;
    else if (B->key == NULL)
        return INT_MIN;
    else
        return memcmp(A->key,B->key,A->size);
}
void print_node(tnode *node)
{
    //Useful for debugging
    int i;
    printf("\nThis Nodes LBA is:%d\nNumber of Keys in node:%x\n",node->lba,node->nkeys);
    for (i = 0; i <= node->nkeys; ++i)
        print_kv(node->items[i]);
    printf("\n");

}

void print_kv(const kv *item)
{
    if (item->key == NULL)
        printf("\nNULL Key who's lba is: %d\n",item->lba);
    else
        printf("\nAddress:%p\nKey:%s\nLBA:%d\nSize:%d\n",item,item->key,item->lba,item->size);
}

unsigned int tnode_insert(tnode *node, kv *item)
{
    //Insert key & val in node
    node->items[++node->nkeys] = item;

    print_node(node);

    printf("Started sorting\n");
    qsort(node->items,node->nkeys,sizeof(kv),compare_key);


    print_node(node);

    return item->lba;
}
```

What this outputs:

```sh
This Nodes LBA is:1
Number of Keys in node:4

Address:0x19c6a00
Key:Alexis
LBA:4
Size:200

Address:0x19c6a20
Key:Allison
LBA:11
Size:200

Address:0x19c6a40
Key:Caleb
LBA:10
Size:200

Address:0x19c6a60
Key:Daniel
LBA:2
Size:200

NULL Key who's lba is: 6

Started sorting

Address:0x19c6380
Key:?j?
LBA:27028000
Size:0

Address:0x19c6390
Key:`l?
LBA:27028064
Size:0

NULL Key who's lba is: 0

NULL Key who's lba is: 0

Address:0x19c63a0
Key:
LBA:27024960
Size:0

NULL Key who's lba is: 0

Address:0x19c6380
Key:?j?
LBA:27028000
Size:0

Address:0x19c63a0
Key:
LBA:27024960
Size:0

Address:0x19c6390
Key:`l?
LBA:27028064
Size:0

Address:0x19c63a0
Key:
LBA:27024960
Size:0

This Nodes LBA is:1
Number of Keys in node:5

Address:0x19c6a00
Key:Alexis
LBA:4
Size:200

Address:0x19c6a20
Key:Allison
LBA:11
Size:200

Address:0x19c6a40
Key:Caleb
LBA:10
Size:200

Address:0x19c6a60
Key:Daniel
LBA:2
Size:200

NULL Key who's lba is: 6

Address:0x19c5e40
Key:Bob
LBA:12
Size:200

Insert return value: 12
```

What I gather is that what I'm doing with quicksort is incorrect but I have no idea what that is. I tried to follow the gnu license but I'm stumped. Perhaps the comparison function assumes all the structs are continuous? Help would be very much appreciated.

UPDATE:
Changing to sizeof(kv*)

```sh
This Nodes LBA is:1
Number of Keys in node:4

Address:0x1dc3a00
Key:Alexis
LBA:4
Size:200

Address:0x1dc3a20
Key:Allison
LBA:11
Size:200

Address:0x1dc3a40
Key:Caleb
LBA:10
Size:200

Address:0x1dc3a60
Key:Daniel
LBA:2
Size:200

NULL Key who's lba is: 6

Started sorting from:0x1dc3380
*(const kv **) a:0x1dc3a00
Address:0x1dc3380
Key:?:?
LBA:31210016
Size:0

Address:0x1dc3388
Key:?;?
LBA:31210048
Size:0

Address:0x1dc3398
Key:0=?
LBA:31210112
Size:0

Address:0x1dc33a0
Key:
LBA:31206976
Size:0

Address:0x1dc3390
Key:`<?
LBA:31210080
Size:0

Address:0x1dc3398
Key:0=?
LBA:31210112
Size:0

Address:0x1dc3380
Key:?:?
LBA:31210016
Size:0

Address:0x1dc3390
Key:`<?
LBA:31210080
Size:0

Address:0x1dc3388
Key:?;?
LBA:31210048
Size:0

Address:0x1dc3390
Key:`<?
LBA:31210080
Size:0

This Nodes LBA is:1
Number of Keys in node:5

Address:0x1dc3a00
Key:Alexis
LBA:4
Size:200

Address:0x1dc3a20
Key:Allison
LBA:11
Size:200

Address:0x1dc3a40
Key:Caleb
LBA:10
Size:200

Address:0x1dc3a60
Key:Daniel
LBA:2
Size:200

NULL Key who's lba is: 6

Address:0x1dc2e40
Key:Bob
LBA:12
Size:200

Insert return value: 12
Reads: 3
Writes: 1
```

Comment: Show [mcve] please.

Comment: Did you know that quicksort performs worst on lists that are almost sorted?  If you care about performance, then it would be better to insert at the correct place.

Comment: I'm just looking for the quick and dirty sort that's reliably correct.

Comment: @stark `qsort` is not necessarily quicksort. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353904/what-sorting-algorithm-does-qsort-use

Comment: `sizeof(kv)` should be `sizeof(kv*)`? You have an array of pointers for `items`. Better `sizeof *node->items` and you will never get your type-size wrong if you use the dereferenced pointer.

Comment: `const kv *A = (const kv *) a;` - shouldn't it be  `const kv *A = *(const kv **) a;`?

Comment: Yes, in your compare function, you must handle the additional level of indirection. Since you are sorting pointers, the parameters to compare will be *pointer-to-pointer* so you must remove the additional level of indirection.

Comment: It starts to segfaults after changing type cast to "const kv *A = *(const kv **) a;" that because it takes on an illegal value 0f 0xffff... not sure why. I'm just sorting an array of kv struct pointers so wouldn't it be kv*? not *(const kv **)

Comment: Did you change `sizeof(kv*)` in the `qsort` call?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, it changed the size to 8 bytes. It then just incremented the value from 10 bytes to 8 bytes from base. It did not use the value at that place but the address at that spot if that makes sense. I'll post new output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The compare function is passed addresses to elements. You sort array of pointers. So compare function receives a pointer to the pointer in the array. Do:

   ```
   int compare_key(const void *a,const void *b)
   {
       const kv *A = *(const kv *const *)a;
       const kv *B = *(const kv *const *)b;
   ```
2. You have an array of pointers and you are sorting pointers, not `kv` structs. You have to pass a pointer as the size of element.

   ```
   qsort(node->items, node->nkeys, sizeof(kv*), compare_key);
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I was using the compare function in two cases but for different data structures which caused a segfault when I changed the code. I made two compare function for keys now. Thanks again